# Rendering with Cycles has hot spots on glass surfaces

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, glass, hdri

Rendering with Cycles has hot spots on glass surfaces. I'm using an HDR image to light scene and its labeled as 'high noon' so sun angle is straight down. I am wondering why I am getting a 'hot spot' reflection on all the glass surfaces? It really is strange because there really shouldn't be all of that reflection. I have played around with a lot of settings for bounce, etc. but obviously not changing the right settings because the adjustments do nothing to alleviate the render. I can look closely and tell it is the reflection of something distant but in real-world and looks terrible.

Not sure what happened as I did add screenshot with original post...here it is again.
[image]

TIA!

Cheers!

Rick...

Comment: I think you will be more likely to get a quality answer if you post a render showing your exact issue.

Comment: you probably forgot to remove the lamp... xD

Comment: I re-added screenshot not sure how it was removed from original message...